# c# - Resource files - Is there a limit to the number of items in these files? .net windows form project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms

I had entered my sql into a resource file for access on a specific table(select/insert) and had no problem.  2 entries.  I was trying to add the connection string, and I kept getting resource not found when I tried to reference it.  I ended up created another resource file in my project, and all of a sudden.  It worked.  These are string entries only, no other binaries or anything else.

So, is there a limit to the number of entries?

Visual Studio 2022 community

Now that I am thinking about this, this might be way more readible to have a resource file for each table.  But I would like to know for  future reference.

Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no provision for the Number of Entries of resource files in WinForms. This often depends on your hard disk size and computer processing speed.

However, adding a large number of files to the resource file of the WinForms project may cause the program to load longer, because these files will be embedded in the program concentration, resulting in more data that needs to be loaded when the program starts.

So in addition to resource files, you can also use the following methods:

1. Put the file on the outside [Reading files asynchronous](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-s/dotnet/csharp/asynchronous-programming/using-async-file-Access). You can speed up reading.
2. Use SQLServer to store files, such as storage audio pictures, you can use SQLSERVER Image or Varbinary (MAX). Image is a fixed -length binary data type that can store the maximum length of 2 GB of data, but it has been abandoned in the new version of SQL Server. It is recommended to use Varbinary (MAX) instead. VARBINARY (MAX) is a variable -length binary data type that can store the maximum length of 2 GB of data and is suitable for most binary data storage. This method is suitable for the need to manage and retrieve the files.

Comment: hmmm, I just want to add my sql statements so the files will not be large.  I currently am using sql lite as the db for the actual data.  Thank you for the response, this gives me a couple of ideas of how to deal with this.  This win form is for my personal use, but I still would rather be doing things correctly.